# jquery show/hide scale doesnt work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I'm trying to make a div appear proportionally in their width and height at the same time both. And the same to disappear, but I can not do it. Are there any other way better to do it? Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/693xw/

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('a.close').click(function() { 

        $('#box').hide("scale",{percent: 0, direction: 'vertical', origin: ['bottom','left']},1000);       
        $('#box').hide("scale",{percent: 0, direction: 'vertical', origin: ['top','right']},1000);

});
//});
$('#show').click(function() {


        $('#box').show("scale",{percent: 100, direction: 'vertical', origin: ['bottom','left']},1000);       
        $('#box').show("scale",{percent: 100, direction: 'vertical', origin: ['top','right']},1000);

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the fiddle[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/693xw/11/)

```
 $('a.close').click(function() { 
    $('#box').hide("scale",
        {percent: 0, direction: 'both', origin: ['bottom','middle']},1000);       
});

$('#show').click(function() {
    $('#box').show("scale",
        {percent: 100, direction: 'vertical', origin: ['bottom','middle']},1000);       
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to change the `direction` parameter to `'both'`:

http://jsfiddle.net/693xw/7/

```
    $('a.close').click(function() { 
        $('#box').hide("scale",
            {percent: 0, direction: 'both', origin: ['middle','middle']},1000);       
    });

    $('#show').click(function() {
        $('#box').show("scale",
            {percent: 100, direction: 'vertical', origin: ['bottom','left']},1000);       
    });
```

There are other ways to achieve this: You could describe this scaling effect as a CSS animation in a CSS file rather than achieve it using jQuery.

Edit:
http://api.jqueryui.com/scale-effect/ has not only jQuery documentation on this effect, but includes two demos. The first one is essentially just `"scale"` with no other parameters, and seems to already do just what you want, at least for me using Chrome. Here's the key part of their code:

```
    <p>Click anywhere to toggle the box.</p>
    <div id="toggle"></div>

    <script>
      $( document ).click(function() {
        $( "#toggle" ).toggle( "scale" );
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).hide( "slow", function() {
    //your css method or function
  });
});
```

Try this method

Comment: I would like get something similar to in DEMO (show), to hide() the #box div

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to fix this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/693xw/13/

HTML

```
<input type="button" name="show" id="show" class="show" value="Show">
<div id="box" style="display:none;">
<a href="#" class="close">Close</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('a.close').click(function() { 
    $('#box').animate({
        width:"5px",
        height:"5px",
        opancy: "toggle"
    },1000);         
});
//});
$('#show').click(function() {
    $('#box').show().animate({
        width:"200px",
        height:"200px",
    },1000)      
});
```